# In Rails, how can I protect an attribute from mass assignment while still allowing the attribute to be set when the object is first created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mass-assignment

I've only been working with Rails for a few months now so I may be missing something obvious, but if an attribute is protected from mass assignment by `attr_accessible`, or `attr_protected`, how do you set that attribute when you first create a record? (And do it in a way that is still secure.)

---

**For example:**

Say I'm working on an application that keeps track of different procedures and processes that employees in a company have been trained on.

As part of this application, I have three models: `User`, `Course`, and `TrainingClass`. `User` represents employees, `Course` represents different things employees can be trained on, and `TrainingClass` represents a specific class in which employees will be trained on a course.

The `TrainingClass` has a `belongs_to` relationship with both the `Course` model (because a class is basically just a specific instance of a course) and the `User` model (because the class has a single instructor, who is the user who creates the `TrainingClass`). Similarly, the `Course` and `User` models both have a `has_many` relationship with the `TrainingClass` model.

Based on that information, how would I go about creating a new record for `TrainingClass`?

I could say:

```
course.training_classes.build(user_id: user.id)
```

or

```
user.training_classes.build(course_id: course.id)
```

But wouldn't that be mass assignment on the `user_id` or `course_id` attributes?

What would be the best way to do this while still keeping the application secure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about [Mass Assignment Security](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html), specifically **roles**.

You could have

```
class TraningClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible .....
  attr_accessible ....., :user_id, as: :create
end
```

Where `......` is your list of other attributes you want accessible for mass assignment. Then when you call `build`, you'll pass that role

```
course.training_classes.build({user_id: user.id}, as: :create)
```

Repeat similarly for your other models. The default role will be used *(the first one)* unless you specify the `:create` role when calling `build`, `create!`, etc...

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was looking for. One minor thing though; in  your example `user_id: user.id` needs to be enclosed in braces {}, otherwise Rails interprets `as` as just another parameter to be assigned to the `TrainingClass`. (I'd make the correction myself, but apparently StackOverflow won't let me make edits less than 6 characters long? What's with that?)